# Creating indexes of highest value in struct for top 5

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

Lets say i have a struct below

```
struct info
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    double kids;
    double income;
    double cars;
    int index;
};
```

Lets say i have 500 people in this struct, each containing the information first, last name, kids, income and cars.

I created a int called index so that i can sort who has the most income from highest to least.

What method would you use or how would you go about finding the top 5 people with the most income, and giving them an index as 1,2,3,4,5 etc. So that i can tell who the top 5 are if i wished to print their names out.

I am looking for a simple method as im still learning about trees and such.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

vector of structs. Supply a specialized function for comparison that gets called during sort.
the specialized compare function shall compare based on income (descending order)
the first top 5 elements from sorted vector should give your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the top 5 (and don't need them in order) you can use `std::nth_element` to find them. This is normally faster than sorting.

If you do want the top 5 in order, you could use `std::partial_sort` to do the job, something like this:

```
std::partial_sort(x.begin(), x.begin() + 5, x.end(), 
                  [](auto a, auto b) { return b.income < a.income; });
```

Note that I've swapped the two parameters when comparing them to get it to sort in descending order instead of ascending.

I don't see a very good way to use the `index` field you've put into the structure. To work very well, you'd want the index separate from the data you're sorting, and you'd do an indirect sort on the indexes (that is, you'd sort the indexes based on the income for the item at that index).